# How can I interact with payable functions on frontend?

Tags: javascript, function, frontend, solidity

This is my code, I have problem on calling the function from frontend, how can I make function in JS which can interact with my function in smartcontrat?

```
   function placeBet(uint8 matchID, string memory bettingType, uint8 oddForWinning) override external payable MBet {
    require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bettingType)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Tie")) || keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bettingType)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Team A")) || keccak256(abi.encodePacked(bettingType)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked("Team B")), "Betting type must be 'Team A' or 'Team B' or 'Tie'");
    bets[msg.sender] = Bet(matchID, bettingType, oddForWinning, msg.value);

    players.push(msg.sender);
  
    string memory b = "Bet received!";
    emit UpdatedBet(msg.sender ,b);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to interact with a Smart Contract is via an API.
You can then expose the functions of the smart contract via API endpoints (GET/PUT/POST etc).

The right tools to help you achieve that are: [Web3.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/), [Trufflesuite](https://trufflesuite.com/docs/) and [Ethairballoons](https://github.com/petrosDemetrakopoulos/ethairballoons).

Then, from the front-end part of your application, you can easily call the API services through which you expose the smart-contract functionality.

Comment: function placeBet(){
        
        var contractAddress = '0xABDcA1e209f4d671E927F744D871eb71B2b46CC2';
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider)
        signer = provider.getSigner()
        abi = ...
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);}

Comment: This is my code in JS, i dont know what to tpye in contract.placeBet()..

Comment: You have to call contract.methods.placeBet(arg1, arg2, arg3).send() as it is a function altering the state of the contract. You can read more on this link: https://bitsofco.de/calling-smart-contract-functions-using-web3-js-call-vs-send/